# Asymptotic growth of summation of $\sum_{j\leq t}' 2^{\omega(j)}$ (restricting sum to a certain subset of $j$)

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, analytic-number-theory, dirichlet-series

The following question came up in a thesis discussion I had with a student (undergraduate). I am a number theory researcher, but not within analytic number theory. One challenge I have faced is not having good intuition for what the answers should be (unless I see clearly a proof, which then creates a vicious circle!).

Here is the question asked in its most basic form. Recall that $\omega(n)$ is used to denote the number of distinct prime divisors of $n$. Let me call an integer $n$ *good* if for all primes $p \mid n$, we have $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$.

**What is the asymptotic behavior of $\displaystyle D(t) = \sum_{\substack{n\leq t\\\text{$n$ good}}} 2^{\omega(n)}?$**

What I seem to be able to see right now is that $D(t) = ct + o(t^{3/4})$ where $c = \frac{2\sqrt{2}\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{\pi^2}$ (see below). The issue is that the error term seems grossly overestimated. So, I am turning to you all to ask what better trained people can say about the sum $D(t)$.

Now I explain where this arises and what I know. The sum $D(t)$ arises from counting a certain set of ideals in the algebraic integer ring $\mathbf Z[\sqrt 2]$. Namely, $D(t)$ counts the number of pairs of ideals $I,J \subseteq \mathbf Z[\sqrt 2]$ such that $N(I) = N(J)$ and $\gcd(I,J) = 1$. Here $N(I)$ is the ideal norm (if $I$ is generated by $a+b\sqrt{2}$ then $N(I) = |a^2-2b^2|$).

Second, I know just enough technique from analytic number theory to consider the Dirichlet series
$$
F(s) = \sum_{\substack{n\geq 1\\ \text{$n$ is good}}} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}.
$$
This factors nicely into
$$
F(s) = \zeta(s)G(s),
$$
where
$$
G(s) = \prod_{p\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}} (1 + p^{-s}) \times \prod_{p\not\equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}} (1-p^{-s}) = \frac{1-2^{-s}}{1-2^{-2s}}\frac{L(s,\chi_8)}{\zeta(2s)}.
$$
Here, $\chi_8$ is the Dirichet character modulo $8$ that sends $1,7 \mapsto 1$ and $3,5 \mapsto -1$. I guess I should say $\zeta(s)$ is Riemann's zeta function. (Without the restriction to $n$ being good, the series $F(s)$ would have factored into $\zeta(s)^2/\zeta(2s)$.)

If I understand correctly, the Dirichlet series $G(s)$ converges on $\mathrm{Re}(s) \geq 1/2$ (the tricky part is that $1/\zeta(s)$ converges at $s = 1$, which is related to the prime number theorem) and so $G(s) = \sum b_n/n^s$ has partial sums that satisfy $\sum_{n\leq t} b_n = o(\sqrt{t})$. Then, using $F(s) = \zeta(s)G(s)$, I used the hyperbola principle (my most advanced trick, to be honest) to see that
$$
D(t) = G(1) t + o(t^{3/4}).
$$
(If I haven't made any mistake, which is a big iff...).

The value of $G(1)$ can be calculated to be $\frac{2\sqrt{2}\log(1+\sqrt{2})}{\pi^2}$ using the famous formula for $\zeta(2)$ and the evaluation of $L(1,\chi_8)$ either by the class number formula or just doing it by hand.

For what it's worth, I plotted $D(t) - ct$ for $t \leq 20000$ (first plot) and $t \leq 100,000$ (second plot) and, well, the difference looks small, way better than just $o(t^{3/4})$ but not as small as $O(1)$...

[First plot. Values of $D(t) - ct$ for $t \leq 20000$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Gecx9.png)

[Second plot. Values of $D(t) - ct$ for $t \leq 100000$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CtJQf.png)

(apparently noobs cannot post images...)

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are right @John Omilean. Also, while reflecting on what is written I also see that if you take $F(s)/L(2s,\chi_8)$ you basically get $\zeta_{\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})}(s)/\zeta_{\mathbf Q(\sqrt{2})}(2s)$, which is related to counting square-free ideals. Maybe that is something I missed...it would give an error like $O(\sqrt{t})$.

Comment: I only know enough about Analytic Number Theory to know that there are problems where it's easy to get an error term on the order of, say, $n^{1/2}$, very hard to get any improvement on that, but calculations suggest the error term is actually on the order of $n^{1/4}$. If a few days go by and you haven't received an answer here, you might post the question to MathOverflow (being sure to link each question to the other).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $f(n)$ be the multiplicative function satisfying $f(p^r) = 2$ if $p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}$ and $f(p^r) = 0$ otherwise. Then
$$\sum_{\substack{n = 1 \\\ n \text{ good}}}^{\infty} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s} = \sum_{n = 1}^{\infty} \frac{f(n)}{n^s}.$$
This is
$$\prod_p \sum_{r = 0}^{\infty} \frac{f(p^r)}{p^{rs}} = \prod_{p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}} \left(1 + \sum_{r = 1}^{\infty} \frac{2}{p^{rs}}\right) = \prod_{p \equiv \pm 1 \pmod{8}} \frac{1 + p^{-s}}{1 - p^{-s}}.$$
Letting $\chi_8$ denote the quadratic Dirichlet character modulo $8$ that satisfies $\chi_8(1) = \chi_8(7) = 1$ and $\chi_8(3) = \chi_8(5) = -1$, we find that this is
$$\frac{1 - 2^{-s}}{1 - 2^{-2s}} \prod_p \frac{1 - p^{-2s}}{(1 - p^{-s}) (1 - \chi_8(p) p^{-s})} = \frac{1 - 2^{-s}}{1 - 2^{-2s}} \frac{\zeta(s) L(s,\chi_8)}{\zeta(2s)}.$$
This is all valid for $\Re(s) > 1$. Now we use Perron's formula, which states that if $x > 1$ is not an integer,
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \int_{\sigma_0 - i\infty}^{\sigma_0 + i\infty} \frac{1 - 2^{-s}}{1 - 2^{-2s}} \frac{\zeta(s) L(s,\chi_8)}{\zeta(2s)} \frac{x^s}{s} \, ds$$
for any $\sigma_0 > 1$. (If $x$ is an integer, we have to subtract $f(x)/2$.)

We truncate the integral to be from $\sigma_0 - iT$ to $\sigma_0 + iT$ for a parameter $T$ to be chosen, then shift the contour to the left, picking up a residue at the pole at $s = 1$ equal to $\frac{4 L(1,\chi_8)}{\pi^2} x$. This special value can be explicitly determined via the Dirichlet class number formula. The new contour should be chosen to be $\sigma_1 - iT$ to $\sigma_1 + iT$, where $\sigma_1 = 1/2 - c/\log T$ with $c$ a small positive constant chosen to ensure that this is inside the zero-free region for $\zeta(2s)$. In this way, we don't pick up any additional residues at the poles of $1/\zeta(2s)$. Now one estimates the contour integrals using various standard bounds for the integrands and picks the optimal choice of $T$.

This method of proof hopefully should be able to show that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n) = \frac{4 L(1,\chi_8)}{\pi^2} x + O\left(\sqrt{x} e^{-c\sqrt{\log x}}\right)$$
for some absolute constant $c > 0$. Assuming the Riemann hypothesis, one should be able to show that
$$\sum_{n \leq x} f(n) = \frac{4 L(1,\chi_8)}{\pi^2} x + O_{\varepsilon}\left(x^{\frac{1}{4} + \varepsilon}\right).$$
Unconditionally, one can show that this is essentially optimal, in that the error term cannot be $o(x^{1/4})$.

The caveat is that I haven't estimated the contours, which is a nontrivial amount of work (that I can't be bothered doing).

Comment: Thank you for your response and direction(s) to look in. I'm glad to see what an expert thinks is provable and what is optimal. Best,